# How to get the text from HTML data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup

How can I get all the text with the same arrangement while using python 3 and beautifulsoup 4. I tried a for loop but it didn't work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<body>
    <div id="Select">
        <h1 id="wall">
            First
        </h1>
    </div>

    </div>
        <div id="color_acts">
        <p id="acts_h">
        Choose
        </p>
        <p id="actshead">
        Color
        </p>
        <p id="acts">
        Blue
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Select">
        <h1 id="wall">
            Second
        </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div id="color_acts">
        <p id="acts_h">
        Choose
        </p>
        <p id="actshead">
        Color
        </p>
        <p id="acts">
        Green
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for Colors in soup.find_all('div', id='Select'):
    CC = Colors.find('h1').text
    print(CC)
    SS = soup.find('div', id='color_acts')
    print(SS)
```

My output:

```
            First

<div id="color_acts">
<p id="acts_h">
        Choose
        </p>
<p id="actshead">
        Color
        </p>
<p id="acts">
        Blue
        </p>
</div>

            Second

<div id="color_acts">
<p id="acts_h">
        Choose
        </p>
<p id="actshead">
        Color
        </p>
<p id="acts">
        Blue
        </p>
</div>
```

My expected output:

```
    First

Choose
Color
Blue

    Second

Choose
Color
Green
```

Note that my intended output has blue then green, but the actual output just has the color blue twice. How can I get the output to have the right colors and prevent the html tags from printing?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the right color printed? Your output has Blue twice, your intended output has Blue then Green. Or do you mean that you want to remove the HTML tags from your print?

Comment: Both. Removing the HTML tags and getting the right output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your issue is that you're just using `soup.find` to get the first div with the id `'color_acts'`, that means it keeps finding the first div. It will never grab the second one this way, hence you just get Blue as the colour twice. You should loop over `zip(soup.find_all('div', id='Select'), soup.find_all('div', id='color_acts'))`. What this does is it will mean that you find all the divs with id of 'Select' and 'color_acts' and iterate over them at the same time. Then you can access each of those divs together and print from them, like this:

```
for header, body in zip(soup.find_all('div', id='Select'),
                        soup.find_all('div', id='color_acts')):
```

Now, as for removing the tag info. You call on `.text` for the first case, but not the second. You probably had trouble with `.text` before, but now that you have the div we could just print out `body.text`:

```
for header, body in zip(soup.find_all('div', id='Select'),
                        soup.find_all('div', id='color_acts')):
        print (header.find('h1').text)
        print (body.text)
```

You may get unnecessary whitespace this way as I did, but you can just use split to separate the words by whitespace and then use `'\n'.join` to rejoin it as a single string:

```
        print ('\n'.join(body.text.split()))
```